# is it possible to check a variable with a list of method?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to pass a string into a series of method. These method will check whether the string have all properties needed. so, if the string didn't meet the requirement on one validator method, it will return false.

example :
input : "customerid=cu01","name=someone","phone=+628770xxxxx","address=somewhere","balance=500000"
output : true

another example :
"customerid=cu01","name=someone","address=somewhere","balance=200000"
output : false (no phone number)

Is it possible to create a list of validator class like this

```
List<Validator> val = new ArrayList<Validator>();
val.add(ValidatorA);
val.add(ValidatorB);
etc.
```

so i can check the string with that list of validator. i just want to know, is it possible to check a string with a list of validator like that? i'm doing this because it will be easier to add another validator if needed someday.

thanks

Comment: Simple way is create custom class and override hashcode and equals method.

Comment: Yes its possible. Whats wrong with that?

Comment: i always get null pointer exception. my bad maybe, i'll try it again

Answer (score 0):

You could use the decorator pattern.
Take a look at this example I think it suits your usecase:
http://blog.decarufel.net/2009/09/using-decorator-or-wrapper-design.html

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator

```
public abstract class ValidationObject {
    String description = "no particular";

    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }
}


public class Account extends ValidationObject {
    public Account(){
        description = "account";
    }
}


public class Book extends ValidationObject {
    public Book () {
        description = "book";
    }
}


public abstract class ValidationObjectDecorator extends ValidationObject {
    public abstract String getDescription();
}


public class ValidationOne extends ValidationObjectDecorator {

    private ValidationObject account;

    public ValidationOne (ValidationObject g) {
        account = g;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return account.getDescription() + "+ validationOneRan";
    }

    public void validateStuff() {
        System.out.println("Big validation!");
    }
}
We can add more method like "validateOtherStuff()" to each decorator without any limitations.



public class ValidationTwo extends ValidationObjectDecorator {

    private ValidationObject book;

    public ValidationTwo(ValidationObject g) {
        book = g;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return book.getDescription() + " ran validationTwo";
    }

    public void validationMethod() {
        System.out.println("Big Validation!");
    }
}


package designpatterns.decorator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ValidationObject g1 = new Account();
        System.out.println(g1.getDescription());

        ValidationOne g2 = new Account(g1);
        System.out.println(g2.getDescription());

        ValidationTwo g3 = new Book(g2);
        System.out.println(g3.getDescription());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can create an interface which will define a function such as "validate()", create implementations of this interface and then iterate over the list and apply the validate function.

Example:

```
public interface validator{
    public boolean validate();
}
class validateUserName{
    public boolean validate(){
         return true;
    }
}
class validatePhone{
    public boolean validate(){
          return false;
    }
}

List<Validator> list = new ArrayList<Validator>();
list.add(new validPhone());
list.add(new validUserName());


for(Validator v : list)
    v.validate();
```